# Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server version 5.1.38. This may cause unpredictable behavior

Tags: windows, mysql, php

I am using phpmyadmin and I am getting the following error at the bottom of the page when I log in.

Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server version 5.1.38. This may cause unpredictable behavior.

Where would I get the correct version of libmysql.dll from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try reinstalling PHP. [Here are the PHP installers for Windows](http://windows.php.net/download/).

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: Now that's odd... If I have more ideas I'll let you know.